# Relation of spoken sentence length and processing time required

Tags: language-processing

I would like to know if there is some good research that tried to put spoken sentence length and its processing time in simple relation without focusing on meaning of words etc. It would be nice to know results for a big range of sentence lengths (from 2 words to 10 words, at least).
I've found some answers for reading time (where relation appears to be linear) on this site, but that is not quite what I'm interested in.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the working memory?

Comment: I think it does, but I expect there to be more factors which would eventually lead to more and more processing time needed (thus, worse than linear)